# WPF List control with header

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, wpf-controls

I'm new to WPF. I trying to display information in a scrollable list/grid that has a header and the user is NOT allowed to click on the items in the list. Also I need a divider between each item in the list.

Right now I'm using a `HeaderedContentControl` and putting a `ListView` in the `HeaderedContentControl.Content`. I can't seem to get the `ListView` to scroll without setting a specific height on it and it would be nice to have the control be able to resize.

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <HeaderedContentControl Margin="10">
            <HeaderedContentControl.Header>
                <Label ... />
            </HeaderedContentControl.Header>
            <HeaderedContentControl.Content>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Info1}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Info2}" />
                                <Separator />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </HeaderedContentControl.Content>
        </HeaderedContentControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In the past I've been able to get a ListView scrolling if I put it as a direct child of Grid, but here it's not picking up the height of * as the constraint.

Comment: ListView GridView.  If the ListView does not have a constrained height it will not scroll.  * is a constrained size.  Auto is not a constrained size.

Comment: This is *not* a website that you can come to and say 'What should I do?', because that is off topic, as there are too many answers and not one correct answer. Instead, please provide your code and state the problem that you are having with that code... better still, say something like 'I'm trying to do XYZ with this code, but I am stuck with part ABC'. You'll get much better answers this way and your question won't be closed for being off topic.

Comment: sorry about that. hopefully my edit helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a datagrid? Based on your description I created the following xaml and tested and I believe it satisfies your requirements.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HeadersVisibility="Column" 
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"
              CanUserSortColumns="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              IsHitTestVisible="True"
              CanUserReorderColumns="False" Height="100"
              >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header1" Binding="{Binding Info1}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header2" Binding="{Binding Info2}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

The IsHitTestVisible must be set false in the cell style and column header style to allow the scroll bar to still work.

Datagrids have a lot more properties which you may be able to exploit to get exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Here you have 2 columns. I only want 1 column but with both Info1 and Info2. I tried something similar with another control before but couldn't figure out how to add the data template properly. Do you know how?

Comment: There is a complicated way to override the load event and re-draw the column headers but the only examples I can find weren't much use to me. See here [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4a3f5639-8c2b-4a86-ae08-28abb9c8f845/how-to-merge-two-column-headers-in-a-datagridview). I think the simplest way will be to revert back to the listview and use a constrained size.